# ERROR 123\ ROBOCOPY

Tags: cmd, batch, msdos

estoy intentando copiar con una archivo de lotes otro a carpeta Inicio pero me da este error.

```
Inicio: miércoles, 6 de marzo de 201915:01:10
   Origen : C:\Users\USUARIO\Desktop\prueba.bat\
     Destino : C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\

    Archivos: *.*

  Opciones: *.* /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

2019/03/06 15:01:10 ERROR 123 (0x0000007B) Obteniendo acceso al directorio de origen C:\Users\USUARIO\Desktop\prueba.bat\
```

Por favor, ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Answer (score 1):

Robocopy, copia carpetas enteras, por lo tanto el origen `C:\Users\USUARIO\Desktop\prueba.bat\` lo considera como un path y una carpeta llamada prueba.bat y dentro de ella, lógicamente habrá ficheros que copiará a la carpeta de destino.

Esto significa que:  `Robocopy C:\Users\USUARIO\Desktop\prueba.bat\ C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\`

Cogerá todos los ficheros de origen y los dejará en el destino, no un solo fichero en concreto. Si por el contrario se trata de un fichero `prueba.bat` que hay en el escritorio, deberás hacer `Robocopy C:\Users\USUARIO\Desktop\ C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\` y te dejará todos los ficheros del escritorio en tu destino, incluido `prueba.bat`

Si solo quieres un fichero, utiliza XCOPY por ejemplo.

Comment: Ahora me sale : el sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado 
 (        C:\Users\USUARIO\Desktop\prueba.bat\   )

Comment: Echa un vistazo a la respuesta modificada